# Using `backdrop-filter: blur` with `mix-blend-mode`, the color of text doesn’t show correctly

Tags: css, css-filters, mix-blend-mode

I’m using `backdrop-filter: blur` on the `article` element to blur the background picture, and `mix-blend-mode: overlay` on the `h1` element for some colors.

I was expecting something like this below (a mockup created with *Sketch*), but the actual title always comes out as a shade of gray instead of the varying colors expected (Tested with Chrome and Safari, as Firefox doesn’t yet support `backdrop-filter` as of now).

### Expected outcome (mockup)

[image: Expected outcome]

### Reproduction sample

```css
article {
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}

h1 {
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}


/** Other styles **/

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/9IBqihqhuHc");
  background-size: cover;
}

article {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 4em;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 small {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>
    <h1><small>Augue amet tempus sed cursus</small><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecturer!</h1>
    <p>Tellus urna parturient cras nulla eleifend purus posuere venenatis malesuada, aliquam dui pellentesque eros nisl porta tempor ligula. Metus ligula mauris vestibulum dictumst luctus interdum volutpat tristique, feugiat accumsan tellus senectus aenean
      curae vel facilisis, ad lacus sed imperdiet penatibus dictum habitasse. Eros porta pulvinar posuere ac semper dictumst id, ad taciti convallis curabitur etiam nam. Libero venenatis lacus faucibus per erat ut aenean vestibulum nostra, pulvinar netus
      luctus vel auctor blandit penatibus eleifend nibh donec, tempus ridiculus accumsan fames in est sodales vivamus. Praesent ut tempus parturient integer elit orci porta montes placerat nibh, iaculis cum per ipsum quis nullam diam sit tincidunt duis,
      dictumst aenean netus mattis purus vehicula vestibulum dignissim laoreet. Ipsum nibh nec nisl netus dapibus etiam felis cubilia sociis in convallis, duis tempor bibendum vestibulum hendrerit suscipit leo fringilla mauris vulputate non, mattis aenean
      integer hac orci dolor ligula ornare sem porta. Aliquet tellus integer dis sit inceptos urna amet dui odio consectetur ac et, aenean eros viverra sapien tempus arcu cras rhoncus cubilia cursus nunc, dignissim velit ante conubia congue platea taciti
      sodales volutpat metus diam.</p>
    <p>Sollicitudin convallis penatibus sed nec suspendisse a vel sem, egestas nostra fusce nam curae potenti class, mi neque at facilisi nibh nullam facilisis. Interdum duis hendrerit quam rutrum platea donec purus pharetra egestas, hac aliquam dictum taciti
      varius leo dis sit consequat, auctor magna feugiat urna quisque mauris dolor congue. Natoque fermentum tristique tempus iaculis lacus facilisi, congue placerat torquent ultricies quis, a ridiculus ullamcorper viverra egestas varius, himenaeos scelerisque
      vestibulum nisi. Urna odio nec netus dui sodales non nam id fusce magnis commodo proin placerat pretium, ultrices nostra senectus diam at massa metus habitasse elementum ornare varius aliquam. Cum pharetra sapien faucibus accumsan massa litora,
      duis aptent ullamcorper dis sollicitudin elit, vitae vel quam dictum venenatis. Etiam rutrum iaculis faucibus nec elementum luctus eros eleifend, feugiat posuere nostra congue penatibus ac fames. Pellentesque platea lorem nulla dui libero himenaeos
      inceptos tortor convallis mollis condimentum, ac cum arcu egestas tincidunt ultricies posuere orci nostra dictum, nascetur aliquet tempor sem sodales urna maecenas adipiscing vehicula fermentum.</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to make only the `h1` blending with the background. Either it's all the article element or not.

Another idea is to consider background coloration applied to the h1 using the same image as the container:

```css
article {
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}

h1 {
  background: url("https://source.unsplash.com/9IBqihqhuHc") fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  background-clip:text;
  color:transparent;
}


/** Other styles **/
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/9IBqihqhuHc");
  background-size: cover;
}

article {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 4em;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 small {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>
    <h1><small>Augue amet tempus sed cursus</small><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecturer!</h1>
    <p>Tellus urna parturient cras nulla eleifend purus posuere venenatis malesuada, aliquam dui pellentesque eros nisl porta tempor ligula. Metus ligula mauris vestibulum dictumst luctus interdum volutpat tristique, feugiat accumsan tellus senectus aenean
      curae vel facilisis, ad lacus sed imperdiet penatibus dictum habitasse. Eros porta pulvinar posuere ac semper dictumst id, ad taciti convallis curabitur etiam nam. Libero venenatis lacus faucibus per erat ut aenean vestibulum nostra, pulvinar netus
      luctus vel auctor blandit penatibus eleifend nibh donec, tempus ridiculus accumsan fames in est sodales vivamus. Praesent ut tempus parturient integer elit orci porta montes placerat nibh, iaculis cum per ipsum quis nullam diam sit tincidunt duis,
      dictumst aenean netus mattis purus vehicula vestibulum dignissim laoreet. Ipsum nibh nec nisl netus dapibus etiam felis cubilia sociis in convallis, duis tempor bibendum vestibulum hendrerit suscipit leo fringilla mauris vulputate non, mattis aenean
      integer hac orci dolor ligula ornare sem porta. Aliquet tellus integer dis sit inceptos urna amet dui odio consectetur ac et, aenean eros viverra sapien tempus arcu cras rhoncus cubilia cursus nunc, dignissim velit ante conubia congue platea taciti
      sodales volutpat metus diam.</p>
    <p>Sollicitudin convallis penatibus sed nec suspendisse a vel sem, egestas nostra fusce nam curae potenti class, mi neque at facilisi nibh nullam facilisis. Interdum duis hendrerit quam rutrum platea donec purus pharetra egestas, hac aliquam dictum taciti
      varius leo dis sit consequat, auctor magna feugiat urna quisque mauris dolor congue. Natoque fermentum tristique tempus iaculis lacus facilisi, congue placerat torquent ultricies quis, a ridiculus ullamcorper viverra egestas varius, himenaeos scelerisque
      vestibulum nisi. Urna odio nec netus dui sodales non nam id fusce magnis commodo proin placerat pretium, ultrices nostra senectus diam at massa metus habitasse elementum ornare varius aliquam. Cum pharetra sapien faucibus accumsan massa litora,
      duis aptent ullamcorper dis sollicitudin elit, vitae vel quam dictum venenatis. Etiam rutrum iaculis faucibus nec elementum luctus eros eleifend, feugiat posuere nostra congue penatibus ac fames. Pellentesque platea lorem nulla dui libero himenaeos
      inceptos tortor convallis mollis condimentum, ac cum arcu egestas tincidunt ultricies posuere orci nostra dictum, nascetur aliquet tempor sem sodales urna maecenas adipiscing vehicula fermentum.</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

You can also consider multiple background and use `background-blend-mode`

```css
article {
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}

h1 {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff),
    url("https://source.unsplash.com/9IBqihqhuHc") fixed
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode:overlay;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  background-clip:text;
  color:transparent;
}


/** Other styles **/
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/9IBqihqhuHc");
  background-size: cover;
}

article {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 4em;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 small {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>
    <h1><small>Augue amet tempus sed cursus</small><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecturer!</h1>
    <p>Tellus urna parturient cras nulla eleifend purus posuere venenatis malesuada, aliquam dui pellentesque eros nisl porta tempor ligula. Metus ligula mauris vestibulum dictumst luctus interdum volutpat tristique, feugiat accumsan tellus senectus aenean
      curae vel facilisis, ad lacus sed imperdiet penatibus dictum habitasse. Eros porta pulvinar posuere ac semper dictumst id, ad taciti convallis curabitur etiam nam. Libero venenatis lacus faucibus per erat ut aenean vestibulum nostra, pulvinar netus
      luctus vel auctor blandit penatibus eleifend nibh donec, tempus ridiculus accumsan fames in est sodales vivamus. Praesent ut tempus parturient integer elit orci porta montes placerat nibh, iaculis cum per ipsum quis nullam diam sit tincidunt duis,
      dictumst aenean netus mattis purus vehicula vestibulum dignissim laoreet. Ipsum nibh nec nisl netus dapibus etiam felis cubilia sociis in convallis, duis tempor bibendum vestibulum hendrerit suscipit leo fringilla mauris vulputate non, mattis aenean
      integer hac orci dolor ligula ornare sem porta. Aliquet tellus integer dis sit inceptos urna amet dui odio consectetur ac et, aenean eros viverra sapien tempus arcu cras rhoncus cubilia cursus nunc, dignissim velit ante conubia congue platea taciti
      sodales volutpat metus diam.</p>
    <p>Sollicitudin convallis penatibus sed nec suspendisse a vel sem, egestas nostra fusce nam curae potenti class, mi neque at facilisi nibh nullam facilisis. Interdum duis hendrerit quam rutrum platea donec purus pharetra egestas, hac aliquam dictum taciti
      varius leo dis sit consequat, auctor magna feugiat urna quisque mauris dolor congue. Natoque fermentum tristique tempus iaculis lacus facilisi, congue placerat torquent ultricies quis, a ridiculus ullamcorper viverra egestas varius, himenaeos scelerisque
      vestibulum nisi. Urna odio nec netus dui sodales non nam id fusce magnis commodo proin placerat pretium, ultrices nostra senectus diam at massa metus habitasse elementum ornare varius aliquam. Cum pharetra sapien faucibus accumsan massa litora,
      duis aptent ullamcorper dis sollicitudin elit, vitae vel quam dictum venenatis. Etiam rutrum iaculis faucibus nec elementum luctus eros eleifend, feugiat posuere nostra congue penatibus ac fames. Pellentesque platea lorem nulla dui libero himenaeos
      inceptos tortor convallis mollis condimentum, ac cum arcu egestas tincidunt ultricies posuere orci nostra dictum, nascetur aliquet tempor sem sodales urna maecenas adipiscing vehicula fermentum.</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion! I’ve added an SVG filter based on your solution to include background blur too. CodePen: https://codepen.io/blueset/pen/OJNMGej

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `mix-blend-mode` on the parent `article`:

```css
article {
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}

/** Other styles **/

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/9IBqihqhuHc");
  background-size: cover;
}

article {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 4em;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 small {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>
    <h1><small>Augue amet tempus sed cursus</small><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecturer!</h1>
    <p>Tellus urna parturient cras nulla eleifend purus posuere venenatis malesuada, aliquam dui pellentesque eros nisl porta tempor ligula. Metus ligula mauris vestibulum dictumst luctus interdum volutpat tristique, feugiat accumsan tellus senectus aenean
      curae vel facilisis, ad lacus sed imperdiet penatibus dictum habitasse. Eros porta pulvinar posuere ac semper dictumst id, ad taciti convallis curabitur etiam nam. Libero venenatis lacus faucibus per erat ut aenean vestibulum nostra, pulvinar netus
      luctus vel auctor blandit penatibus eleifend nibh donec, tempus ridiculus accumsan fames in est sodales vivamus. Praesent ut tempus parturient integer elit orci porta montes placerat nibh, iaculis cum per ipsum quis nullam diam sit tincidunt duis,
      dictumst aenean netus mattis purus vehicula vestibulum dignissim laoreet. Ipsum nibh nec nisl netus dapibus etiam felis cubilia sociis in convallis, duis tempor bibendum vestibulum hendrerit suscipit leo fringilla mauris vulputate non, mattis aenean
      integer hac orci dolor ligula ornare sem porta. Aliquet tellus integer dis sit inceptos urna amet dui odio consectetur ac et, aenean eros viverra sapien tempus arcu cras rhoncus cubilia cursus nunc, dignissim velit ante conubia congue platea taciti
      sodales volutpat metus diam.</p>
    <p>Sollicitudin convallis penatibus sed nec suspendisse a vel sem, egestas nostra fusce nam curae potenti class, mi neque at facilisi nibh nullam facilisis. Interdum duis hendrerit quam rutrum platea donec purus pharetra egestas, hac aliquam dictum taciti
      varius leo dis sit consequat, auctor magna feugiat urna quisque mauris dolor congue. Natoque fermentum tristique tempus iaculis lacus facilisi, congue placerat torquent ultricies quis, a ridiculus ullamcorper viverra egestas varius, himenaeos scelerisque
      vestibulum nisi. Urna odio nec netus dui sodales non nam id fusce magnis commodo proin placerat pretium, ultrices nostra senectus diam at massa metus habitasse elementum ornare varius aliquam. Cum pharetra sapien faucibus accumsan massa litora,
      duis aptent ullamcorper dis sollicitudin elit, vitae vel quam dictum venenatis. Etiam rutrum iaculis faucibus nec elementum luctus eros eleifend, feugiat posuere nostra congue penatibus ac fames. Pellentesque platea lorem nulla dui libero himenaeos
      inceptos tortor convallis mollis condimentum, ac cum arcu egestas tincidunt ultricies posuere orci nostra dictum, nascetur aliquet tempor sem sodales urna maecenas adipiscing vehicula fermentum.</p>
  </article>
</div>
```